# Get political/school district of an address

Tags: json

I need to be able to get political district data (possibly with a GET) for NYC, given a physical address. So I'll be sending an address and I'd like to get back "District 9", e.g. I need this for a FileMaker database so ideally, JSON would be nice.

I've been scraping data from here: https://www1.nyc.gov/apps/311utils/addressinfo.htm  but now I want to process this from the server.

Any ideas where I can get this from? Thank you.

Comment: google address api has this info I think

Comment: I'll check, thank you.

Comment: I searched through and couldn’t find anything useful.